# "Амбидентатный лиганд" или "амбидентный лиганд"

Tags: переводы

На страничке "[Ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand#Ambidentate_ligand)" в Википедии наткнулся на **ambidentate ligand**:

> Unlike polydentate ligands, **ambidentate ligands** can attach to the central atom in two places. A good example of this is thiocyanate, SCN−, which can attach at either the sulfur atom or the nitrogen atom. Such compounds give rise to linkage isomerism.

В гугле около 40 ссылок с сочетанием "амбидентатный лиганд", и меньше десятка с сочетанием "амбидентный лиганд".

Как правильнее? Может быть, оба варианта допустимы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *амбидент**ат**ный*. Это сравнительно редко употребляемый русский термин, но он этимологически и по смыслу связан с родственными ему широкораспространёнными терминами "монодентатный", "бидентатный".... "полидентатный" (лиганд, координированный соотв. через один, два или более донорных атомов).

http://www.ngpedia.ru/id126697p1.html

http://www.chem21.info/info/5430/

Comment: Да, сейчас только прочитал английскую фразу, где о различии полидентатного и амбидентатного. Убрал предположение о синонимах. Но этимология явно общая; без этого суффикса можно уйти в область стоматологии :) .